# How to use removeSpan() on android textview?

Tags: java, android, html

Pardon me if I'm asking a dumb question but I would like to know how to remove a span from text in my textview. This is how my span method looks like.

```
public CharSequence setTextStyleItalic(CharSequence text) {
    StyleSpan style = new StyleSpan(Typeface.ITALIC);
    SpannableString str = new SpannableString(text);
    str.setSpan(style, 0, text.length(), 0);
    return str;
}
```

and this is how i call it.

```
tvTitle.setText(setTextStyleItalic(tvTitle.getText()));
```

I would really like to know how to remove this italic span in java using removeSpan() please.

Comment: use getSpans() method to acess the text and then clear it by using removeSpan() method

Comment: @hs.chandra is it possible for you to come out with a method for me as a reference? Sorry, I'm new to this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Get the text of the `TextView` and cast it to `SpannableString` then you can use the `getSpans(int queryStart, int queryEnd, Class<T> kind)` method to iterate over those spans and remove them

```
SpannableString ss=(SpannableString)txtView.getText();
ForegroundColorSpan[] spans=ss.getSpans(0, txtView.getText().length(), ForegroundColorSpan.class);
for(int i=0; i<spans.length; i++){
  ss.removeSpan(spans[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First get text from your span using getSpans()

```
  removeTextSpan = tvTitle.getSpans(0, tvTitle.getText().length(),ForegroundColorSpan.class);
  for (int i = 0; i < removeTextSpan.length; i++) 
  tvTitle.removeSpan(removeTextSpan[i]);
```

i think this will help

Comment: Is it helped for your query?

Comment: What class is `tvTitle`? And how do you go about this if your starting reference is of type `TextView` that doesn't have `getSpans()`?

Answer (score 0):

Set and remove span for ITALIC

```
 val spannable: Spannable = SpannableStringBuilder(editText.text)
 val start = editText.selectionStart
 val end = editText.selectionEnd

 val allSpans: Array<StyleSpan> = spannable.getSpans(0,
                spannable.length, StyleSpan::class.java)

         if (doItalic) {
               spannable.setSpan(
                   StyleSpan(ITALIC), start, end,
                   Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
                  )
             } else {
                 for (span in allSpans) {
                     if (span.style == ITALIC)
                        spannable.removeSpan(span)
                    }
                }
 editText.setText(spannable)
```